# Enabling time aware layers using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, time

Is it possible to enable time aware on a layer programmatically? I can add a time-enabled layer to a non-time aware data frame as shown here:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000023000000.htm

However, how can I get the layer to be time enabled in the first place (programmatically)?

I see that it is possible in arcobjects but I would rather not get into that.

Comment: I am having the same issues and was wondering if anyone knows if this is at all possible in Arc 10.1.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for using this site!  If the question being asked doesn't answer your question, consider asking a new question.  Stackexchange works in a Q&A format rather than a conversation thread format.

Comment: Any updates on that problem? How can you enable time on a layer with Python? It's so simple in ArcMap, only a checkbox to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time-aware layers are not in Python in 10.0, so at that version you'll need to use ArcObjects.

However, from [What's new for automating map workflows in ArcGIS 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//016w00000022000000):

> ArcGIS 10.1 provides access to a [layer's time](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000063000000) properties to
>   perform analysis over time. You can also enable time on layers.